# creating a trigger for snmp item in zabbix

Tags: triggers, snmp, zabbix

I have a problem in defining a trigger for a SNMP item in zabbix. The SNMP OID is 'IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10001' & the key is 'inbound_traffic10001' for the item.

The item stores Delta (simple change) & update interval is set 20 120 seconds.

I have defined a trigger with the following expression:

```
{Template SNMP-v2 Switch C3750:inbound_traffic10001.last()}>2000000
```

I want the trigger fires if the inbound traffic of the port 1 of the switch goes over 2MBs.

But the problem is that the traffic goes over 2MB but the trigger does not fire!!!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the full item configuration - for example, is the multiplier set? Can you show some of item values that you think should have made the trigger fire, but did not?

Comment: The type of item is snmpv2 agent, key is inbound_traffic10001, SNMP OID is IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10001. Only the store value is Delta (Simple Change) because I want to monitor the bandwidth and there is no extra configuration such as multiplier.

Comment: "Store value" should be `Delta (Speed per second)`.

Comment: WoW. Thank you @Richlv. I changed Stored value to Delta (Speed per second) and it seems to be worked. But why it is not working in simple change mode!! Also another question: is the number in the triiger (e.g. 2000000) in bytes?

Comment: `Simple change` is functionally different, so of course it's not giving you traffic. The trigger threshold is in whatever units your item returns, but it's better to have a separate question for each topic.

Comment: Thanks @Richlv, You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discovered through the discussion, the "Store value" setting in the item should be set to `Delta (Speed per second)`.